# kafka-server-stop.sh not working on RedHat7

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, redhat

The default Apache kafka service is started with an extra  parameter
**$EXTRA_ARGS kafka.Kafka**

The stop kafka script looks for this parameter and kills the processes 
**ps ax | grep -i 'kafka.Kafka' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -SIGINT**

This used to work till Linux RedHat6 (also works on AIX).
However on RedHat7, the command **ps ax | grep -i 'kafka.Kafka'** does not find any process and thus does not find the PIDs.
With RH7, the result returned by ps ax | grep kafka is truncated.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to stop running server $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh

Comment: The kafka-server-stop.sh script contains only the above line of code which is failing.

`ps ax | grep -i 'kafka.Kafka' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -SIGINT`